# Linkedin API get public-profile

Tags: rest, linkedin-api

I am trying to get the `id` from the `public-profile-url`. The query looks like:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url={https://www.linkedin.com/in/name}
```

However, what I get get back from linkedin is:

```
<error>
 <status>400</status>
 <timestamp>1460131755319</timestamp>
 <request-id>2OV9FJ0DTR</request-id>
 <error-code>0</error-code>
 <message>[invalid.param.url]. Public profile URL is not correct,
 {url=}; should be {https://www.linkedin.com/pub/[member-name/]x/y/z} or
 {https://www.linkedin.com/in/string}</message>
```

The interesting part is:

`Public profile URL is not correct, {url=}; should be {https://www.linkedin.com/pub/[member-name/]x/y/z} or {https://www.linkedin.com/in/string}`

The `url` clearly adheres to the rules that they mention and the url works. Any idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot reliably retrieve a member ID from a profile URL. `id` values that you can rely on are returned as part of Profile API calls.   From time to time, LinkedIn changes the format of it's public profile URLs, so attempting to parse them or reconstruct them can leave your app in a broken state.  The `public-profile-url` field should be considered read-only, and not something you try and parse or create yourself.

e.g.: `GET https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,public-profile-url)?format=json`

`id` values are encoded to specific LinkedIn applications and cannot be re-used between apps.  As a result, any value you attempt to pull out of a URL won't be of any use to you.  The information needs to be acquired via an API call.